# Which architecture should I install on Samsung N145 Plus?

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-netbook, samsung, architecture

I have a Netbook Samsung N145 plus and I want to know which of Ubuntu versions is the best for me. I will use GCC compiler on Ubuntu and some other programs for code development (Netbeans, Eclipse).

> Processor: Intel Atom N455 1.6 Ghz (x64 copatible)
>   RAM: 1 GB

I want to know, can I install x64 Ubuntu 12.10 and how it can work on my device?

Comment: My question is "How about RAM? Would it work fine with 1GB RAM?"

Comment: See the [32-bit vs. 64-bit Ubuntu 13.04 Linux Performance article at Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_x86_1304&num=1)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you install Lubutnu.  Just to give you an idea, I have a Pentuim 3 computer with 768MB RAM, and 8MB built-in VGA.  I have tried running Ubuntu 12.04, and it installed, and ran OK.  To me it was very slow.  I have installed Lubuntu 11.10, and it runs perfect.  Well having said that, and the fact that your machine specs are far more better, I would recommend that you take a look at lubuntu.

[Click Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) for Ubuntu system requirements

[Click Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) For Lubuntu system requirements